# Step-by-Step checkout with multiple subscription products

Tags: onepage-checkout, recurring

I'm a complete magento rookie so forgive me but can anyone tell me what plugins/addons this site is using? https://perkyjerky.com/ - I'd be trying to achieve the monthly 'box' approach where users select multiple items from a list of 'products' within that category and that then becomes their recurring subscription product based on number of items selected.

So almost like one product with multiple options I suppose.

It'd be a bonus if users could alter their subscription products after the fact. So if I ordered 5 of product #1 I could log in and change that to 4 of product #1 and 1 of product #2 for instance.

thanks!

Comment: Hi, "Shopping list" questions are not a good fit for StackExchange Q&A (see this question on [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad)) - you'll get better results at the [Magento forums](https://community.magento.com/t5/Find-an-Extension-that/bd-p/find-extension) or [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Magento/).

Answer (score 0):

From the look of it, this is a custom feature that was built out by a development agency. So i don't think this is an "out of the box" site and there might not be a "out of the box" solution to what you are looking to do.

[image]

[image]

The author tagged themselves in the script file. Might worth your time to contact them directly.